# Remove items from specific positions on recyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `recyclerView` and a `List<>` which contains some random position

All i want to do is remove `recyclerView` item from `position` stored in the list.

Comment: you can call remove(Object)

Comment: remove the item from the recyclerView's source and refresh the adapter

Comment: I've been trying remove(object) but it requires an int value....the values i have are in a list which produces an error

Comment: What do you mean by **position**? Is it an **index** of an array or **x y coordinate**?

Comment: It has values like {3, 36, 54}
I want to remove these values on these positions in recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to remove the object from Adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged`.

Comment: For `RecyclerView` you have `notifyItemRemoved(position)` which is much better and keeps the animations.

Answer (score 0):

from your activity you can loop your list of item position you want to delete

```
for(int i = 0; i< listitem.size(); i++){adapter.deleteItem(position);}
```

then in your adapter implement removeItem function:

```
public void deleteItem(int index) {
    Dataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}
```

Comment: use iterator while looping and changing dataset items.

Comment: I know its been late. internet connections in my city were shut down due to some political issue. I'm not able to write Dataset.remove(index). it says remove is not any method

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a single item in RecyclerView adapter with:

```
List<YourData> list;

// position of your data in the list.
private removeItem(int position) {
  list.remove(position);
  notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

But you can't use it if you need to remove multiple items sequentially. The following won't work:

```
removeItem(3);
removeItem(36);
removeItem(54);
```

because the list index has been changed after the first call of `removeItem()`.

So, you need to depend on an Id for your data. For example, with the following User class:

```
public class User {
  private long id;
  private String name;

  // constructor
  // setter
  // getter

}
```

you can remove multiple items sequentially by checking the id with the following method:

```
// list of your User
List<User> users;

// id is your User id
private removeItem(int id) {
  for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    User user = users.get(i)
    if(user.getId() == id) {
      users.remove(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used if you know the id:

```
removeItem(3);
removeItem(36);
removeItem(54);
```

Of course, you can add another method to remove items by using a list of id:

```
private removeItems(List<Integer> ids) {
  for(Integer id: ids) {
    removeItem(id);
  }
}
```